# Edit specific row of a table using id of that row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have displayed some values from database in form of a table using php. One column of the table is reserved for edit. I wish that each row of the table can be edited.

Code for edit is

```
echo"<td class='success'><button class='btn blue' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myeditModal'>Edit </button></td>";
```

Code used in modal is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myeditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edut Treatment</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="edit.php?id="$row['id']"" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"> Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="name" >
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit" name="submit">

                            <span></span>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for edit.php page is

```
<?php
include('admin_session.php');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE treatment_type SET name='".$name.'" WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: abc.php");
?>
```

My problem is that when I reach the `edit.php` page I get the url as this: `http://example.com/xyz/edit.php?id=`

I am not able to carry the id due to which I am not able to edit a specific row of the table.

Comment: Can you show the definition and a var dump of $row?

Comment: Well I would say you gotta use javascript or jquery for this to be able to pass the row to the edit modal, then do an ajax call to display the edit page.  Otherwise youll be outputing multiplt modal pages to your page

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 You are right!

Comment: 8 upvotes? I just don't see it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are enable to call the URL just fine. Most likely because of this line on the UPDATE statement:

```
WHERE id='".$id."'");
          ^^^^^^^
```

Second, properly echo the row id:

```
action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"
```

And make sure `$name` is defined.

And why not use prepared statements instead:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['name'])) {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $sql = 'UPDATE treatment_type SET name = ? WHERE id = ?';
    $update = $con->prepare($sql);
    $update->bind_param('si', $name, $id);
    $update->execute();

    if($update->affected_rows > 0) {
        header("Location: abc.php");
    } else {
        echo 'did not update';
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 yes i understand its flow. when the modal is opened, it will show a form with all the fields in it. i think the main problem is that `echo $row['id'];`. since the `id` is not echoed properly, when its submitted, the form is not able to send the id well.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 well, there are some missing parts that needs to be addressed since we don't know how the OP echoes the id into the form. actually kyle's answer above is good, if the OP puts and uses our answers both this should address those issues. don't worry no offense taken :)

Comment: @Ghost i am still getting the same issue and while using prepared statement i got error in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in update query and i am not able to remove it

Comment: @Sam just remove the typo and check the revision

Comment: @Ghost now i am not getting any error but the url still remains http://example.com/xyz/edit.php?id= . Id is not getting the value

Comment: @Sam why did you have a `$row['id']` in there anyway?

Comment: @Ghost i have  table and each row has a edit button when the user clicks on it a model gets opened and i want that when the edited value is entered it gets updated in the same row with help of the id of that specific row

Comment: @Sam actually, what you can do is combine both mine and kyles answer. that should get it going, print the id in the edit button, then use jquery to put the id inside the form and append it onclick. after the operation, just use my solution on php

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it now, you need to change to this..

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="edit.php?id='<?php echo $row['id'];?>'" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

To output the ID corerectly into the form.

But this way you are ouputting multiple different modal forms for each row??

You should really just display the modal once, then pass the ID via jquery/javascript to the modal, do an ajax request-display the data, and then edit it.

If its just one row, it should be fine,  But if you want multiple table rows, with the ability to edit any value in the row, then you definitely need to use ajax/jquery/javascript

Example using one modal window, and passing ID via jquery...

PHP

```
echo"<td class='success'><button class='btn blue editButton' data-id='<?php echo $row['id'];?>' >Edit </button></td>";
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //Click button, apply id, and open modal.
    $('.editButton').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      //Apply action with id to form
      $('#myForm').attr('action','edit.php?id='+id);
      //Open modal 
      $('#myModal').modal({background:'static'});
     }):

    //If you want values to come into the modal you need to do a sepereate ajax call to get the one particular element from database.


     });
```

Comment: i am still getting the same url and the i am getting the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in update query

Comment: Well then you're obviously not showing how you are getting the results and looping through to apply the $row variable to the form.  Seems like row contains nothing.  your need to use mysql_fetch_array and loop it